# run an asp.net application with IIS

Tags: asp.net

Hello I am trying to run my asp.net application in IIS. When I run it from Visual Studio it runs well. When I try to run it from IIS, i get an error. I mean when I create a virtual directory and do it. I think it's unable to read data from the database.

Am I missing something. I am using IIS 7.

Comment: I imagine the first thing you are missing is the actual error you have received.  Without posting it here no one can help you.

Comment: We will need more information to be able to help you without randomly guessing at the problem. Are there errors/exceptions? What process are you following? Log files?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing quite a bit.  The most likely problem, based on the limited information available, is that you've simply created the folder and copied the files in, but haven't set the web app as an Application in IIS.  It could also be that your application pool is not set correctly, or any number of issues that stem from improper configuration.

I strongly recommend checking the documentation, using this as a starting point: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/150/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis/

Unless you've configured your web app as an Application within IIS, IIS won't know where to look for your web.config files, _bin folder, etc.  It's far too much to answer succinctly here, but the documentation I linked to above is an excellent (if somewhat overwhelming) starting point.

If that's too overwhelming (and I suspect it might be) [this video](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/372/serving-new-content/) gives a gentler introduction.